# Coluna direita do site fixa

Tags: html, css

Tenho um layout com 2 colunas.

1. Coluna Left: Conteudo
2. Coluna Right: Diversas Informações

quando o usuário está navegando no site, rolando o mouse para baixo o conteúdo da direita acaba ficando visível só o da esquerda 
Como deixar a coluna da direita fixa na tela quando acabar seu conteudo?

[Exemplo](http://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,dolar-tem-forte-alta-e-inicia-2016-cotado-acima-de-r-4,1817706#)
role o scroll e preste atenção na parte direita do site.

codigo utilizado

```
<div class="content content-center marginTop">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="bounceInLeft animated col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <?php 
                    include 'pages/primeira.php';
                    include 'pages/segunda.php';
                    include 'pages/terceira.php';
                    include 'pages/quarta.php';
                    include 'pages/quinta.php';
                    include 'pages/sexta.php';
                    include 'pages/setima.php';
                    include 'pages/oitava.php';
                    include 'pages/nona.php';
                    include 'pages/decima.php';
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="bounceInLeft animated col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <?php  
                    include 'pages/direita.php';
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito, mas na classe css que você quer deixar fixa coloca a propriedade { position: fixed; } e vai ajustando as propriedades de posicionamento do elemento.

Answer (score 1):

Não achei muitos exemplos prontos de como se possa fazer isso, então resolvi fazer eu mesmo. Veja se é o que deseja:

Crei uma `div` com a `class="sideBar"` que pode possuir ter vários artigos, os "relacionados", ou qualquer outra coisa. Representei isso por várias `div.artigos`.

Ficou assim:

```
<div class="sideBar" >
  <div class="artigos"></div>
  <div class="artigos"></div>
  <div class="artigos"></div>
  <div class="artigos"></div>
  <div class="artigos"></div>
</div>
<div class="conteudo" >
</div>
```

Seus respectivos estilos:

```
.sideBar{
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}
.conteudo{
  width: auto;
  height: 2000px;
  background: #333;
  margin-right: 200px; 
}
.sideBar .artigos{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f30;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Já o código fiz em JQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  var left = $('.sideBar').offset().left;
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.sideBar').height() - $('.artigos:last').height()){
    $('.sideBar').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: -($('.sideBar').height() - $('.artigos:last').height()),
      left: left
    })
  }else{
    $('.sideBar').css({
      position: 'relative',
      top: 0,
      left: '0'
    })
  }
})
```

Usei o evento `.scroll()` do JQuery. Ao rolar a página a primeira coisa que será feita, será a captura do `left` da `.sideBar`. Após isso ele irá 
verificar se o `.scrollTop` do documento é maior que o tamanho da `.sideBar` subtraído com o tamanho do último `.artigos`, e caso seja a `div.sideBar` receberá um `position: fixed`, como este se comporta levando em consideração toda a página, terá um `left` correspondente a captura anterior.  Já o `top` será igual ao tamanho da `.sideBar` subtraído com o tamanho do último `.artigos`, porém negativo (mesmo cálculo da verificação do `scroll`).

Mas caso o `scroll` será inferior ao resultado do cálculo, a `div.sideBar` esta receberá um `position: relative`, e um reset nos `left` e `top`.

## Código Completo

Note que quando a a `div.conteudo` acaba a `div.sideBar` fica fixa, mas caso volte acima, ela volta a correr junto com o restante.

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
  var left = $('.sideBar').offset().left;
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.sideBar').height() - $('.artigos:last').height()){
    $('.sideBar').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: -($('.sideBar').height() - $('.artigos:last').height()),
      left: left
    })
  }else{
    $('.sideBar').css({
      position: 'relative',
      top: 0,
      left: '0'
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.sideBar{
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}
.conteudo{
  height: 2000px;
  background: #333;
  margin-right: 200px; 
}
.sideBar .artigos{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f30;
  margin:0 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sideBar" >
  <div class="artigos"></div>
  <div class="artigos"></div>
  <div class="artigos"></div>
  <div class="artigos"></div>
  <div class="artigos"></div>
</div>
<div class="conteudo" >
</div>
```

### [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drzcvqfp/2/)

Caso tenha dificuldades para implementar em seu código, avise-me.

Comment: Amigo de uma olhada do lado direito http://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,dolar-tem-forte-alta-e-inicia-2016-cotado-acima-de-r-4,1817706# Eu coloquei seu codigo e ficou +-60% como queria.

Comment: No caso devido a responsividade do Bootstrap ele tem alguns problemas como pode ver, mas estou tentando adaptar esse código, quando conseguir aviso.